# How do I stop iptables restoring to an earlier version every reboot?

Tags: networking, server, cron, iptables, firewall

I set rules in iptables a few months back and used `iptables-persistent` to make the rules persist through reboot. I just updated my rules and am trying to make them persist but nothing is working they keep resetting to the earlier version. I have tried:

Creating a cronjob that runs on reboot AND every minute,

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables-restore -c < /home/amart219/iptables.backup
```

I have saved to the file that supposedly is default location of the rules and reconfigured iptables-persistent

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
I have placed a script in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ directory that says the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/iptables-restore < /home/amart219/iptables.backup
/sbin/ip6tables-restore < /home/amart219/iptables.backup
```

I modified the `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
post-down iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules
```

I added iptables-restore and iptables-save to the `if-pre-up.d` and `if-post-down.d` directories in the `/etc/network directory`

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0

#!/bin/sh
iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
if [ -f /etc/iptables.downrules ]; then
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules
fi
exit 0
```

I made sure they were the files were executable.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-post-down.d/iptablessave
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload
```

None of these changes make any difference. My understanding is that dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent is the correct method however nothing I try works. I am afraid that some time in the past I might have attempted to make them persistent in some other way that worked prior to installing iptables-persistent but if so I have no idea how I might have done that. I ran: `tail -500 /var/log/syslog` right after reboot to see if the system loaded anything but I see nothing but the usual boot data. This server has no cron jobs aside from the one that I created trying to restore the iptables setting. I don't know if that is the problem or not, but if it was I don't know how to locate where it might be running from to change it.

If I manually run the script I set up in cron to restore iptables settings, it works just fine but does not persist through reboot. The cronjob is set up properly, on a separate server I have 40+ cronjobs, I am familiar with the process.

Any suggestions? I am not picky on the method I just need it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrea Turbiglio answered my question on another site.  I believe the site is associated with this one but I don't know the rules regarding linking to another site so I am crediting him with the answer and placing it here.

"I used to put the line with "iptables-restore" in /etc/rc.local (tested on both Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04) and it worked just fine."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe third-party firewall program is actived.
check for `ufw` and `firewalld` using

```
dpkg -l | grep ufw
dpkg -l | grep firewalld
```

you may install the corresponding gui tools:

```
sudo apt-get install ufw gufw
sudo apt-get install firewalld firewall-applet
```

Comment: This is a terminal only installation, Ubuntu 16.04, with no GUI.  Ufw is not installed., I am aware of the program but I only ever use iptables.  I would even be willing to try ufw, but I cannot explore that option until I am able to save settings and IP tables since I would need to flush iptables before ufw would work properly